# Excel: Call a VBA library function from a cell formula?

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

Is it possible to call a VBA library function, eg. `StrReverse` (in `VBA.Strings`) directly from a cell formula without writing a wrapper function?

Comment: Have you tried registering the foreign function directly?

Comment: You might try some of the techniques suggested here: http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/RegisterUDF00.asp

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible, you must create a wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe its possible without some kind of wrapper to do the marshalling etc.

Comment: Um, what does marshalling have to do with it?

Comment: Something has to get the argument from the formula, retrieve the relevant data from memory, transform it to the required format and pass it to the function ... marshalling etc.

Comment: Still not sure what you're on about. My wrapper is just `Function StrReverse$(s)
    StrReverse = VBA.StrReverse(s)
End Function`

Comment: So your wrapper function is using Excel and the VBA COM UDF interface stuff to do all the marshalling etc. Your original question asked how to do this without a wrapper.

Comment: I don't even know what the calling conventions are for VBA functions or Excel formulas. There might possibly be marshalling going on but none of it is explicit, which is why I was confused that you brought it up. I think the real issue is that the VBA libraries are not "in scope" to the Excel formulas.

Comment: Sounds like you are using a different definition of marshalling to me?